# Pre populating selectbox using php

Tags: php

I have an issue for which I am not able to think of a solution. 
I have an array of data which I get from the server. I have to pre populate a form which already have some values.

```
<select id="select1" name="Salutation" class="field-size-top-large" >
     <option value="">-- please select -- </option>
     <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
     <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
</select>
```

I am getting an array

```
 array(11) { 
            [0]=> string(4) "Ms." 
            [1]=> string(8) "Y"
           }
```

I have to check if `[0]=>'Ms.'` is there in select list, if there it should be selected else default is selected. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question more ?

Comment: how you populate ur select box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My soultion:
the data array I am getting from the server i.e 0=>'Ms.' is the only value I can check for the rest are different fields

```
 <select id="select1" name="Salutation" class="field-size-top-large" >
     <option value="">-- please select --</option>
     <option value="Mr." <?php echo 'Mr.'== $data[0]? 'selected':''?>> Mr. </option>
     <option value="Ms."<?php echo 'Ms.'== $data[0]? 'selected':''?>>Ms.</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$options = array('Mr.', 'Ms.');
$data = array(0 => 'Ms.', 1 => 'Y');

<select id="select1" name="Salutation" class="field-size-top-large">
    <option value="">-- please select --</option>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option?>" <?php echo $option == $data[0] ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: not exactly the ans I was looking for but your ans gave me a solution.  the data array I am getting from the server i.e  0=>'Ms.' is the only value I can check for the rest are different fields. I solved it anyway with your help. Thank you.

Comment: `<select id="select1" name="Salutation" class="field-size-top-large" >
 <option value="">
  -- please select --
  </option>
  <option value="Mr." <?php echo 'Mr.'== $data[0]? 'selected':''?>>
         Mr.
 </option>
 <option value="Ms."<?php echo 'Ms.'== $data[0]? 'selected':''?>>
         Ms.
 </option>
 </select>` My Solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$options = ['Mr.', 'Ms.']; // the default options
$data = [0 => 'Ms.', 1 => 'Y']; // data from server

<select id="select1" name="Salutation" class="field-size-top-large">
    <option value="">-- please select --</option>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>" <?php echo in_array($option, $data) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I have updated my solution. thank you for your quick help